# How to implement zooming with a mouse wheel in Jetpack Compose Desktop?

Tags: kotlin, zooming, viewport, compose-desktop

I have a desktop application in which i want to implement zooming and panning behaviour, like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969250/how-to-implement-zooming-with-a-mouse-wheel-like-its-done-in-a-typical-graphic), but without scrollbars. However, i don't know how to allow the user to wheel-zoom on an exact point. I'm using Kotlin Compose Multiplatform 1.4.3

Panning works fine, but offset is calculated incorrectly after scaling. The mouse cursor should stay in the same position after zooming.

Here is my code:

```kotlin
fun main() = singleWindowApplication {
    Surface {
        Box {
            PanAndZoom(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.size(300.dp).background(Color.Gray))
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun PanAndZoom(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    state: PanAndZoomState = remember { PanAndZoomState() },
    content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .onPointerEvent(PointerEventType.Scroll) {
                val change = it.changes.first()
                val delta = change.scrollDelta.y.toInt().sign
                val position = change.position

                val posBeforeZoom = state.screenToWorld(position)

                // Zooming
                state.scale(delta)

                val posAfterZoom = state.screenToWorld(position)
                
                // Incorrect offset calculation
                state.offset += (posBeforeZoom - posAfterZoom)
            }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                // Panning
                detectDragGestures { _, dragAmount ->
                    state.offset += dragAmount
                }
            }
            .onGloballyPositioned {
                state.size = it.size
            }
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .matchParentSize()
                .graphicsLayer {
                    with(state) {
                        // Applying transformations
                        scaleX = scale
                        scaleY = scale
                        translationX = offset.x
                        translationY = offset.y
                    }
                },
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            content = content
        )
    }
}

class PanAndZoomState {

    var size: IntSize = IntSize.Zero
    var offset by mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero)
    var scale by mutableStateOf(1f)

    fun scale(delta: Int) {
        scale = (scale * exp(delta * 0.2f)).coerceIn(0.25f, 1.75f)
    }

    fun screenToWorld(screenOffset: Offset): Offset {
        return (screenOffset * scale) + ((size.toOffset() * (1 - scale) ) / 2f)
    }

}

fun IntSize.toOffset(): Offset {
    return Offset(
        x = width.toFloat(),
        y = height.toFloat()
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you can use transformable in Kotlin Compose Multiplatform 1.4.3, but with 1.5.10. I think something like that could work:

```
var scale by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
var rotation by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
val state = rememberTransformableState {
        zoomChange, offsetChange, rotationChange ->
    scale *= zoomChange
    rotation += rotationChange
    offset += offsetChange
}

fun scale(delta: Int) {
    scale = (scale * exp(delta * 0.2f)).coerceIn(0.25f, 1.75f)
}


  Box(
    modifier = modifier
        .graphicsLayer(
            scaleX = scale,
            scaleY = scale,
            rotationZ = rotation,
            translationX = offset.x,
            translationY = offset.y
        )
        .transformable(state = state)
        .fillMaxSize()
        .focusable()
        .onPointerEvent(PointerEventType.Scroll) {
            val change = it.changes.first()
            val delta = change.scrollDelta.y.toInt().sign
            scale(delta)
        } ...
```