# Calculate transform origin to mouse point after scale change

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to calculate the `transform-origin` of svg to mouse point after svg's scale changed.

As you can see in the snippet, the `transform-origin` is correct at start, but then mouse move to new position and zoom again, the `transform-origin` is not the position where mouse is.

I had found some solutions that use `translate` to move the svg/img/canvas to correct place, but in my case `translate` has already used in drug function.

How can I fix this problem?

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React;

const App = () => {
  const boxRef = useRef(null);
  const svgRef = useRef(null);
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState({ scale: 1, x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [dragStatus, setDragStatus] = useState({ moving: false });
  const [translate, setTranslate] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const handleStart = () => setDragStatus({ moving: true });
  const handleEnd = () => setDragStatus({ moving: false });
  const handleMouseDrag = ({ movementX: x, movementY: y }) => {
    if (dragStatus.moving) setTranslate((prev) => ({ x: prev.x + x / zoom.scale, y: prev.y + y / zoom.scale }));
  };
  const handleWheelZoom = ({ clientX, clientY, deltaY }) => {
    // calculate zoom ratio
    let r = deltaY > 0 ? 0.95 : deltaY < 0 ? 1.05 : 1;
    // calculate the mouse position on the box
    let box = boxRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    let x = clientX - box.left;
    let y = clientY - box.top;
    setZoom((prev) => {
      // get new scale
      let scale = prev.scale * r;
      scale = scale < 1 ? 1 : scale > 5 ? 5 : scale;
      // calculate the new transform origin based on distance between current mouse position and previous position
      let newX = ((x - prev.x) / prev.scale) * scale + prev.x;
      let newY = ((y - prev.y) / prev.scale) * scale + prev.y;
      return { scale: scale, x: newX, y: newY };
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="box" ref={boxRef} style={{ width: "300px", height: "300px", outline: "1px solid black", margin: "auto" }} onWheel={handleWheelZoom} onMouseDown={handleStart} onMouseUp={handleEnd} onMouseMove={handleMouseDrag}>
      <svg style={{ transform: `scale(${zoom.scale}) translate(${translate.x}px,${translate.y}px)`, transformOrigin: `${zoom.x}px ${zoom.y}px`, background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)" }} ref={svgRef} width="300" height="300">
        <rect x={150} y={150} width={140} height={140} fill="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(<App />);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100dvh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I end up using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74283303/18229259), setting the translate and scale by ```style={{ translate: `${zoom.x + drag.x}px ${zoom.y + drag.y}px`, scale: `${zoom.scale}` }}```.