# css scale a div to point centered within parent (transform-origin)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm making a mapbox with zoom +/- buttons that update the scale() property of a 'map' div that contains an image inside of a parent 'viewport' div. The map div is repositioned using css translate on mouse drag.

I'm not sure if this is possible with CSS but I want the map to zoom/scale to the point which is centered within its viewport. The idea was to update the transform-origin of the map div based on its positioning within the viewport. However, since css transforms operate from the transform-origin changing the transform-origin causes unwanted shifting of the map div no matter where I call a function to update it or how I separate the transforms applied to nested child divs for the map.

Is there anyway to handle this with CSS? Essentially something like the below snippet, if it were possible (transform-origin cannot be applied within the transform property).

```
mapRef.current.style.transform = `transformOrigin(centerX, centerY) scale(${zoom.current})`;
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could share a codepen / sandbox of the HTML/CSS/React code in question

Comment: @millhouse there are a handful of functions that I'm using to calculating the center point of the viewport, useRef values to store positions/scales/zoom and event handlers. I'm not sure if snippets of them would help answer the basic question. It's really just a matter of whether or not the functionality is possible with css

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74283303/18229259) maybe helpful for you.